# iPhone:navigation bar "back" button clickable = NO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know that we can hide navigation bar "back" button. But I dont whant to hide it ! Is there any way to make it just not clickable ?

Comment: What UI are you building that required you to disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
```

**Update:**

It seems to be Apple doesn't allow the back button to enable / disable. Instead of that we can hide it.

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Your first options helps me self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO; Thanks a lot...!!!

Comment: I dont know why but self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled=NO not work for me

Comment: Setting `navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO` will disable the *rightBarButtonItem* too. I don't think you want it.

Comment: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;` will not work with default back button. `leftBarButtonItem` will always be `nil`.

Answer (score 11):

You can not disable the *backBarButtonItem*. Setting *enabled* property of *backBarButtonItem* to *NO* doesn't actually disables it.

It seems Apple prevented others("us") from disabling *backBarButtonItem*, even it ignores the *target* and *action* set to *backBarButtonItem*.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

The default cancel button cannot be disabled as Apple does not allow this feature.

Answer (score 2):

**Disable:**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

**Enable:**

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work with the default back button.but it's possible to hide the default back button `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable that button, just setenabled property of that button to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to disable the button:

```
backButton.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not want you to disable it but you can hide it of course.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

This especially works well if you have a custom UIBarButtonItem as a button.

In stock applications you would notice features that are not applicable are hidden altogether rather than disabled.